# Regular expression to match a domain

Tags: regex, google-analytics, subdomain

I want to have a regular Expression for Google Analytic so I can match all the domain including the sub domains

say we have to match a domain name called `xyz.com`

So i want to match every url that have `xyz.com` in it.
Example

```
abcd.xyz.com, abc1232.xyz, www.xyz.com, www.xyz.com/abc
```

Can anyone help me with that.

My purpose to it to have the traafic reports excluded in Google Analytics that are coming from these sites.

Comment: You say you have a regex? What is it? `xyz.com`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word In your specific case, you'd want to match `((?!abc\.com).)*` This will, however, not be a very fast regex.

Comment: Is `abc1232.xyz` really a valid example? Shouldn't this be `abc1232.xyz.com`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the regular expression to match those domains would be something like `.*\.xyz\.com$`. The backslashes escape the dots (which are normally wildcard characters and the dollar-sign represents the end of the string.

There are different regex implementations, so you might have to tweak this for your regex engine.

Comment: The regex engine used by GA is RE2. The `.*` is redundant, since partial matches are accepted. However, the `$` requires a string end, while most addresses do not only contain domain names.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude subdomains like described above you can use GA filter([Exclude] [Hostname] [Matching RegEx]) along with regular expression **(xyz.com)|(.*.xyz.com)**. 
This RegEx including both main domain and it's subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex

`(.*\.)?xyz\.com`

This matches all your required formats for the URL.